# Unexpected token error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm new to node.js and checked out repository from gitlab and succeed to install dependencies.

Then when I run "npm run dev" command I met such a error.
[image]

Here is server.js file.[image]

Lemme know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's a syntax error. I think what you meant to do was `[].forEach((ext) => require(...))` in `line 2`. You use the `>` symbol instead of `.`

Comment: It says unexpected token >

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing server.js lines with these -

```
require('babel-core/register');
require('babel-polyfill');
['.css','.less','.sass','.ttf','.woff','.woff2'].forEach((ext) => require.extensions[ext] = () => {});
require('./src/server/keystone.js');
global.navigator = {navigator: 'all'};
```